# Build Error: A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptWithoutKotlincTask$KaptExecutionWorkAction

Tags: java, android, kotlin, build.gradle, kapt

I'm trying to run and build my project and I keep having this error.

### Build Output

`> Task :app:kaptMyAppQaKotlin FAILED Execution failed for task ':app:kaptMyAppQaKotlin'. > A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptWithoutKotlincTask$KaptExecutionWorkAction > java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)`

### Using (./gradlew assemble --stacktrace --warning-mode all)

> Task :app:kaptMyAppDebugKotlin
> /Users/MyUser/Documents/Projects/Kotlin/MyApp-android/MyApp/app/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/MyAppDebug/com/MyApp/charts/ChartActivity.java:193: error: incompatible types: NonExistentClass cannot be converted to Annotation
> private final void showChartError(@error.NonExistentClass
> ^

> Task :app:kaptMyAppDebugKotlin FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:kaptMyAppDebugKotlin'.

> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptWithoutKotlincTask$KaptExecutionWorkAction
> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)

Here's my ff files.

## build.gradle (MyApp)

```
Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.2'
        classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.3.1'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots' }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

## build.gradle (:app)

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher
import java.util.regex.Pattern

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-parcelize'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

task aaaprintVar {
    doLast {
        println System.getenv('HOME')
        println System.getenv('ANDROID_KEY_ALIAS')
        println project.property("BUILD_NUMBER_TAG")
    }
}

/* AutoVersion Helpers */
def autoVersion_props = new Properties()
def folder = new File("$project.rootDir/scripts")
if (!folder.exists()) {
    // Create all folders up-to and including B
    folder.mkdirs()
}
new File(folder, "autoVersion.properties").withWriterAppend { w ->
    w << ""
}

def autoPropsFile = new File(folder, "autoVersion.properties")
autoPropsFile.withInputStream { autoVersion_props.load(it) }

def readVersionCode = { ->
    def versionCodeString = autoVersion_props.getProperty("gitCommitCount") ?: "0"
    return Integer.parseInt(versionCodeString)
}
/* End AutoVersion Helpers */

android {
    def readVersionName = { ->
        def versionName = autoVersion_props.getProperty("gitVersionTagNumber") ?: "0.0.0"
        return versionName
    }

    def getApplicationIdSuffix = { ->
        return readVersionName() + '-' + readVersionCode() + '+' + gitShortHash()
    }

    def getMyApplicationIdSuffix = { ->
        println("getMyApplicationIddSuffix")
        return readVersionName() + '-' + readVersionCode() + '+' + gitShortHash()
    }

    def gitPrefix = 'asdf'
    // ...
    ndkVersion "21.4.7075529" // or "22.1.7171670"
    // ...
    compileSdkVersion 31
    buildToolsVersion '31.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 31
        buildConfigField "String", "GIT_COMMIT_HASH", "\"" + gitCommitHash() + "\""
        println "VersionCode: " + readVersionCode()
        versionCode readVersionCode()
        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                arguments = ["room.schemaLocation":
                                     "$projectDir/schemas".toString()]
            }
        }
        testInstrumentationRunner 'androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
        dataBinding = true
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude("**/libshinobicharts-android.so")
    }
    flavorDimensions "base"
    productFlavors {
        myapp {
            dimension "base"
            applicationId 'com.me.app'
            versionName readVersionName()
            setProperty("archivesBaseName", getMyApplicationIdSuffix())
            buildConfigField('String', 'HOCKEYAPP_SDK_APP_ID', "\"750acaf49a6a418abdc3d8e36e1d1b83\"")
            manifestPlaceholders = [HOCKEYAPP_APP_ID: "750acaf49a6a418abdc3d8e36e1d1b83"]
        }
        myappinstant {
            dimension "base"
            applicationId 'com.myapp.instant'
            versionName = readVersionName()
            setProperty("archivesBaseName", getMyInstantApplicationIdSuffix())
            buildConfigField('String', 'HOCKEYAPP_SDK_APP_ID', "\"8ee7b2f987d9402c86c0c96dfff52306\"")
            manifestPlaceholders = [HOCKEYAPP_APP_ID: "8ee7b2f987d9402c86c0c96dfff52306"]
        }
    }

    def getCurrentFlavor = {
        Gradle gradle = getGradle()
        String tskReqStr = gradle.getStartParameter().getTaskRequests().toString()

        Pattern pattern

        if (tskReqStr.contains("assemble"))
            pattern = Pattern.compile("assemble(\\w+)(Release|Debug)")
        else
            pattern = Pattern.compile("generate(\\w+)(Release|Debug)")

        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(tskReqStr)

        if (matcher.find())
            return matcher.group(1).toLowerCase() + '-'
        else {
            println "NO MATCH FOUND"
            return ""
        }
    }

    def runAutoVersion = { ->
        try {
            def stdout = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
            exec {
                if (System.getProperty('os.name').toLowerCase().contains('windows')) {
                    commandLine 'cmd', "$rootProject.projectDir/scripts/auto-version.sh"
                } else {
                    commandLine "$rootProject.projectDir/scripts/auto-version.sh"
                }
                args = [getCurrentFlavor()]
                standardOutput = stdout
            }
            return stdout.toString().trim()
        }
        catch (error) {
            println 'Error: ' + error
            return null
        }
    }


    preBuild.doFirst {
        println "PreBuild"
        println "Running auto-version.sh"
        println runAutoVersion()
        project.task("printProps")
    }

    task autoVersion {
        doLast {
            println "PreBuild"
            println "Running auto-version.sh"
            println runAutoVersion()
            println "Finished running auto-version.sh"
            project.task("printProps")
        }
    }


    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }


    def code_sign_props = new Properties()
    def code_sign_file = new File("$rootProject.projectDir/secrets/code_sign.properties")
    def codeSignFile = code_sign_file.exists() ? code_sign_file : file("$rootProject.projectDir/secrets/default_code_sign.properties")
    println("CodeSignFile: " + codeSignFile)
    codeSignFile.withInputStream { code_sign_props.load(it) }
    def keystoreFile = new File("$rootProject.projectDir/secrets/upload.jks")
    def releaseKeyStoreFile = keystoreFile.exists() ? keystoreFile : file("$rootProject.projectDir/../ProjectSetup/qa.keystore")
    println("releaseKeyStoreFile: " + releaseKeyStoreFile)
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile releaseKeyStoreFile
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }
        qa {
            storeFile releaseKeyStoreFile
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }
        release {
            storeFile releaseKeyStoreFile
            storePassword code_sign_props.getProperty("ANDROID_KEY_STORE_PASSWORD") ?: 'android'
            keyAlias code_sign_props.getProperty("ANDROID_KEY_ALIAS") ?: 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword code_sign_props.getProperty("ANDROID_KEY_PASSWORD") ?: 'android'
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            debuggable true

        }
        qa {
            minifyEnabled false
            signingConfig signingConfigs.qa
            debuggable true

        }
        release {
            buildConfigField "Boolean", "RELEASE_TYPE", "true"
            buildConfigField "Boolean", "ENABLE_DEVICE_ID_CHANGE", "false"

            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled false
            //proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }

    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    testOptions {
        unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
    }

}

def gitBranch() {
    def branch = ""
    def proc = "git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD".execute()
    proc.in.eachLine { line -> branch = line }
    proc.err.eachLine { line -> println line }
    proc.waitFor()
    branch
}

def gitShortHash() {
    def hash = ""
    def proc = "git rev-parse --short HEAD".execute()
    proc.in.eachLine { line -> hash = line }
    proc.err.eachLine { line -> println line }
    proc.waitFor()
    hash
}

def gitCommitHash() {
    def hash = ""
    def proc = "git rev-parse HEAD".execute()
    proc.in.eachLine { line -> hash = line }
    proc.err.eachLine { line -> println line }
    proc.waitFor()
    hash
}

dependencies {
    def butterknife_version = "10.2.3"
    def retrofit_version = "2.3.0"
    def okhttp_version = "3.9.0"
    def dagger_version = "2.38.1"
    def hockeyapp_android_sdk_version = "4.1.4"
    def socket_library_version = "2.3"

    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.3.0-alpha02'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.2.0-alpha04'
    implementation "com.jakewharton:butterknife:$butterknife_version"
    kapt "com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:$butterknife_version"
    implementation "net.danlew:android.joda:2.9.9"
    implementation 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.4.0'
    kapt 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.4.0'
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.4.0"
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:2.4.0'
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.4.0"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofit_version"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$retrofit_version"
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:$okhttp_version"
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:$okhttp_version"
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:$dagger_version"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$dagger_version"
    implementation project(':shinobicontrols-android-charts-premium-java-1.9.3-1')
    implementation "net.hockeyapp.android:HockeySDK:$hockeyapp_android_sdk_version"
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:16.0.0"
    implementation "com.neovisionaries:nv-websocket-client:$socket_library_version"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.6"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'

    /* Tests */
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestImplementation('androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1', {
        exclude group: 'androidx', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    testImplementation "com.nhaarman.mockitokotlin2:mockito-kotlin:2.0.0-RC1"
    testImplementation 'androidx.arch.core:core-testing:2.0.0'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version"
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

## gradle-wrapper.properties

`distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME distributionPath=wrapper/dists distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.3.3-bin.zip zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME zipStorePath=wrapper/dists`

I already tried using JDK 20 but error still persist.

Comment: I can't help yet as I'm in the same boat. I'm running Android Studio Flamingo with gradle 8.0 and my understanding is that I'm supposed to use JDK 17.

Comment: Are you on Windows? Running Android Studio "as an administrator" fixed the problem for me.